# FormData to dynamic created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why I can't send file via xhr from the dynamic created element. There is my code:

```
            $('#thread_file').prepend('<form action="/nti/'+$time+'" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><div class="picture" style="text-align:right;height:30px;line-height:15px;">change file</div><input type="hidden" name="thread" value="a" /><input class="file" data-thread="a" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" style="display:none!important;" /><progress value="0" min="0" max="100">0%</progress></form>');
                $('form').on('click','.picture',function(){$(this).parent().find('.file').click();});
                $('form').on('change','.file',function(){
                    var $form = $(this).parent();
                    var data = new FormData($form);
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var $progress_bar = $form.find('progress');
                    xhr.open('post',$form.action);
                    xhr.onload = function(e)
                    {
                        $form.parent().find('.thread_file').html(e.currentTarget.responseText);
                    };
                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) 
                    {
                        $progress_bar.val(e.loaded/e.total*100);
                    };
                    xhr.send(data);
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: I dont understand why you would dump code on us like this and expect us to debug it without anything to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the form dom element to FormData, not a jQuery wrapper object

```
var data = new FormData($form[0]);
```

Same for reading the action param also, since $form is a jQuery object use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to read the value of action attribute or use `$form[0].action`

```
xhr.open('post', $form.attr('action'));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B7sxm/)